# Adding a mask to an Image and copying the region within the mask to another image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pyqt

I succeeded in applying the mask to the image but it only works correctly when the user begins the mask selection from the top left corner of the image form any other anger of the image the region which is being copied is wrong. Here is a snippet of my code

## Function to start the process of adding a mask for the analysis area

```
def add_mask(self):
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mousePressEvent = self.start_mask
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mouseMoveEvent = self.update_mask
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mouseReleaseEvent = self.end_mask

    # Enable the select_roi_button once the add_mask_button has been clicked
    self.select_roi_button.setEnabled(True)

# Function to handle the start of the mask drawing process
def start_mask(self, event):
    rel_position = calc_relative_position(event.pos(), self.analysis_image.pixmap())
    self.mask_rect = QtCore.QRect(rel_position, rel_position)
    self.apply_mask()

# Function to update the mask during the drawing process
def update_mask(self, event):
    rel_position = calc_relative_position(event.pos(), self.analysis_image.pixmap())
    self.mask_rect.setBottomRight(QtCore.QPoint(rel_position.x(), rel_position.y()))
    self.apply_mask()

# Function to handle the end of the mask drawing process
def end_mask(self, event):
    self.update_mask(event)
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mousePressEvent = self.start_mask
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mouseMoveEvent = self.update_mask
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mouseReleaseEvent = self.end_mask

    max_allowed_width = int(250 / self.scale_factor)
    if self.mask_rect.width() > max_allowed_width:
        self.mask_rect.setWidth(max_allowed_width)
        QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', f'Mask area Width cannot exceed 250. Width reduced to 250.',
                            QMessageBox.Ok)

    max_allowed_height = int(1200 / self.scale_factor)
    if self.mask_rect.height() > max_allowed_height:
        self.mask_rect.setHeight(max_allowed_height)
        QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', f'Mask area Height cannot exceed 1200. Height reduced to 1200.',
                            QMessageBox.Ok)

    self.roi_rect = QtCore.QRect(
        self.mask_rect.left(),
        self.mask_rect.top(),
        1,
        self.mask_rect.height()
    )

    self.roi_button = QPushButton(self.analysis_image_duplicate)
    self.roi_button.setGeometry(
        self.mask_rect.right() - 5,
        self.mask_rect.top(),
        5,
        self.mask_rect.height()
    )
    self.roi_button.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeHorCursor)
    self.roi_button.installEventFilter(self)

    self.apply_mask()

# Function to apply the mask to the analysis image
def apply_mask(self):
    if self.analysis_image.pixmap():
        mask_pixmap = self.analysis_image.pixmap().copy()
        painter = QPainter(mask_pixmap)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 1))
        painter.drawRect(self.mask_rect)

        if self.roi_rect:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 1))
            painter.drawRect(self.roi_rect)

        painter.end()

        display_image(self.analysis_image_duplicate, mask_pixmap)

        self.apply_mask_to_template()

# Function to apply the mask to the template image and copy the ROI
def apply_mask_to_template(self):
    if self.template_image.pixmap():
        self.mask_pixmap = self.template_image.pixmap().copy()
        painter = QPainter(self.mask_pixmap)

        if self.analysis_image.pixmap():
            analysis_pixmap = self.analysis_image.pixmap().copy(self.mask_rect)

            # Shift analysis_pixmap to paste_point's coordinates, adjusting for height
            self.target_rect = QtCore.QRect(self.paste_point.x(), self.paste_point.y() - self.mask_rect.height(),
                                            self.mask_rect.width(), self.mask_rect.height())
            painter.drawPixmap(self.target_rect, analysis_pixmap)

        # Set the pen for drawing the blue lines
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.blue, 1, Qt.DashLine))

        # Draw blue lines that cross
        top_line_start = QtCore.QPoint(0, self.target_rect.top())
        top_line_end = QtCore.QPoint(self.mask_pixmap.width(), self.target_rect.top())
        bottom_line_start = QtCore.QPoint(0, self.target_rect.bottom())
        bottom_line_end = QtCore.QPoint(self.mask_pixmap.width(), self.target_rect.bottom())
        left_line_start = QtCore.QPoint(self.target_rect.left(), 0)
        left_line_end = QtCore.QPoint(self.target_rect.left(), self.mask_pixmap.height())
        right_line_start = QtCore.QPoint(self.target_rect.right(), 0)
        right_line_end = QtCore.QPoint(self.target_rect.right(), self.mask_pixmap.height())

        painter.drawLine(top_line_start, top_line_end)
        painter.drawLine(bottom_line_start, bottom_line_end)
        painter.drawLine(left_line_start, left_line_end)
        painter.drawLine(right_line_start, right_line_end)

        if self.roi_rect and self.paste_point:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 1))

            roi_top_left = QtCore.QPoint(max(self.roi_rect.left() - self.mask_rect.left(), 0),
                                         max(self.roi_rect.top() - self.mask_rect.top(), 0))
            roi_bottom_right = QtCore.QPoint(
                min(self.roi_rect.right() - self.mask_rect.left(), self.target_rect.width()),
                min(self.roi_rect.bottom() - self.mask_rect.top(), self.target_rect.height()))
            limited_roi_rect = QtCore.QRect(self.target_rect.topLeft() + roi_top_left,
                                            self.target_rect.topLeft() + roi_bottom_right)

            painter.drawRect(limited_roi_rect)

        # Create left and right part of the mask pixmap
        self.left_part = self.mask_pixmap.copy(0, 0, self.target_rect.left(), self.mask_pixmap.height())
        self.right_part = self.mask_pixmap.copy(self.target_rect.right(), 0,
                                                self.mask_pixmap.width() - self.target_rect.right(),
                                                self.mask_pixmap.height())

        painter.end()

        display_image(self.template_image_duplicate, self.mask_pixmap)
        self.copy_roi_to_template()
```

I tried adding a check to see if the mask selection is being selected in a clockwise or anti-clockwise selection so the region can be copied correctly but it didn’t work. Here is a snippet of my code

## Function to start the process of adding a mask for the analysis area

```
def add_mask(self):
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mousePressEvent = self.start_mask
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mouseMoveEvent = self.update_mask
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mouseReleaseEvent = self.end_mask

    # Enable the select_roi_button once the add_mask_button has been clicked
    self.select_roi_button.setEnabled(True)

# Function to handle the start of the mask drawing process
def start_mask(self, event):
    rel_position = calc_relative_position(event.pos(), self.analysis_image.pixmap())
    self.mask_rect = QtCore.QRect(rel_position, rel_position)
    self.apply_mask()

# Function to update the mask during the drawing process
def update_mask(self, event):
    rel_position = calc_relative_position(event.pos(), self.analysis_image.pixmap())
    self.mask_rect.setBottomRight(QtCore.QPoint(rel_position.x(), rel_position.y()))
    self.apply_mask()

# Function to handle the end of the mask drawing process
def end_mask(self, event):
    self.update_mask(event)
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mousePressEvent = self.start_mask
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mouseMoveEvent = self.update_mask
    self.analysis_image_duplicate.mouseReleaseEvent = self.end_mask

    max_allowed_width = int(250 / self.scale_factor)
    if self.mask_rect.width() > max_allowed_width:
        self.mask_rect.setWidth(max_allowed_width)
        QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', f'Mask area Width cannot exceed 250. Width reduced to 250.',
                            QMessageBox.Ok)

    max_allowed_height = int(1200 / self.scale_factor)
    if self.mask_rect.height() > max_allowed_height:
        self.mask_rect.setHeight(max_allowed_height)
        QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', f'Mask area Height cannot exceed 1200. Height reduced to 1200.',
                            QMessageBox.Ok)

    self.roi_rect = QtCore.QRect(
        self.mask_rect.left(),
        self.mask_rect.top(),
        1,
        self.mask_rect.height()
    )

    self.roi_button = QPushButton(self.analysis_image_duplicate)
    self.roi_button.setGeometry(
        self.mask_rect.right() - 5,
        self.mask_rect.top(),
        5,
        self.mask_rect.height()
    )
    self.roi_button.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeHorCursor)
    self.roi_button.installEventFilter(self)

    self.apply_mask()

# Function to apply the mask to the analysis image
def apply_mask(self):
    if self.analysis_image.pixmap():
        mask_pixmap = self.analysis_image.pixmap().copy()
        painter = QPainter(mask_pixmap)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 1))
        painter.drawRect(self.mask_rect)

        if self.roi_rect:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 1))
            painter.drawRect(self.roi_rect)

        painter.end()

        display_image(self.analysis_image_duplicate, mask_pixmap)

        self.apply_mask_to_template()

# Function to apply the mask to the template image and copy the ROI
def apply_mask_to_template(self):
    if self.template_image.pixmap():
        self.mask_pixmap = self.template_image.pixmap().copy()
        painter = QPainter(self.mask_pixmap)

        if self.analysis_image.pixmap():
            analysis_pixmap = self.analysis_image.pixmap().copy(self.mask_rect)

            # Shift analysis_pixmap to paste_point's coordinates, adjusting for height
            self.target_rect = QtCore.QRect(self.paste_point.x(), self.paste_point.y() - self.mask_rect.height(),
                                            self.mask_rect.width(), self.mask_rect.height())
            painter.drawPixmap(self.target_rect, analysis_pixmap)

        # Set the pen for drawing the blue lines
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.blue, 1, Qt.DashLine))

        # Draw blue lines that cross
        top_line_start = QtCore.QPoint(0, self.target_rect.top())
        top_line_end = QtCore.QPoint(self.mask_pixmap.width(), self.target_rect.top())
        bottom_line_start = QtCore.QPoint(0, self.target_rect.bottom())
        bottom_line_end = QtCore.QPoint(self.mask_pixmap.width(), self.target_rect.bottom())
        left_line_start = QtCore.QPoint(self.target_rect.left(), 0)
        left_line_end = QtCore.QPoint(self.target_rect.left(), self.mask_pixmap.height())
        right_line_start = QtCore.QPoint(self.target_rect.right(), 0)
        right_line_end = QtCore.QPoint(self.target_rect.right(), self.mask_pixmap.height())

        painter.drawLine(top_line_start, top_line_end)
        painter.drawLine(bottom_line_start, bottom_line_end)
        painter.drawLine(left_line_start, left_line_end)
        painter.drawLine(right_line_start, right_line_end)

        if self.roi_rect and self.paste_point:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 1))

            roi_top_left = QtCore.QPoint(max(self.roi_rect.left() - self.mask_rect.left(), 0),
                                         max(self.roi_rect.top() - self.mask_rect.top(), 0))
            roi_bottom_right = QtCore.QPoint(
                min(self.roi_rect.right() - self.mask_rect.left(), self.target_rect.width()),
                min(self.roi_rect.bottom() - self.mask_rect.top(), self.target_rect.height()))
            limited_roi_rect = QtCore.QRect(self.target_rect.topLeft() + roi_top_left,
                                            self.target_rect.topLeft() + roi_bottom_right)

            painter.drawRect(limited_roi_rect)

        # Create left and right part of the mask pixmap
        self.left_part = self.mask_pixmap.copy(0, 0, self.target_rect.left(), self.mask_pixmap.height())
        self.right_part = self.mask_pixmap.copy(self.target_rect.right(), 0,
                                                self.mask_pixmap.width() - self.target_rect.right(),
                                                self.mask_pixmap.height())

        painter.end()

        display_image(self.template_image_duplicate, self.mask_pixmap)
        self.copy_roi_to_template()
```

Comment: Please add details to your problems eg. objective, expected vs current results, your attempt to solve the problem, etc. Its hard to infer these things from the code.

Comment: In what way is the region being copied wrong? What do the wrong results look like?

Comment: Also edit for correct English. I can't understand your words.

Comment: Okay Let me edit the question, can i add screenshots of the outcome